# How to load different CSS based on the category of the post on WP

Tags: css, wordpress, categories

What i am trying to do is call different CSS (for background and other elements) based on the category the post is. It should be very easy, and worked for the pages, but for some reasons it doesn't want to work for categories.

Here is the code I have:

```
 <?php
    if( is_page('Turismo a Bra') || is_page_template( 'turismo.php' ) || is_category('Turismo a Bra')  ) 
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/turismo-a-bra.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />      
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Eventi') || is_page_template( 'eventi.php' ) || is_page_template( 'eventi.php' ) || is_category('Eventi') )
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/eventi.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Arte e Cultura') || is_page('Arte e Cultura') || is_page_template( 'arte.php' ) || is_category('Arte e Cultura'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/arte-e-cultura.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Enogastronomia')|| is_page('Enogastronomia') ||  is_page_template( 'enogastronomia.php' )  || is_category('Enogastronomia'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/enogastronomia.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Natura')|| is_page('Natura') || is_page_template( 'natura.php' )  || is_category('Natura'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/natura.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } else {  ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

As I said, worked perfectly for the page template and the actual page, but not for the categories. I m sur it is very easy, can anybody help me?

Comment: it does not seems to have any problem. but why you repeat is_category() in each condition?

Comment: That was a mistake, I tried everything I could. Type it once, twice, in another condition below. everything. And it looks legit, right? What do you think it might be the problem? Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong method to check category:

According to the wordpress documentation you use `is_category()` for archive pages [(WP Function Reference/is category)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

To check current posts you use `in_category()`  [(WP Function Reference/in category)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<?php if ( is_category('5') ) { // Load special CSS for "Cars" category ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/category-5.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />;
<?php } else { ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } ?>
```

If you are facing problem till now, see link below

http://papahope.com/wordpress/different-css-different-categories/